# Dividing two integers and rounding up result to nearest integer

Tags: java, percentage, division

I have two int numbers a, b always >= 0. I want to divide a by b and return the rounded up percentage to the nearest integer.

Example: 18/38 should return 47 and 13/38 should return 34.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
c = Math.round(a/b) * 100;
```

Comment: a/b is an integer division. You need to cast at least one of the operands to a double to have a double division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` are integers, `a/b` will use [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), and only return the "whole" part of the result. Instead, you should multiply `a` by `100.0` (note the `.0`, which makes it a `double` literal!) to use floating-point division, and then [`ceil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) the result, and truncate it to an `int`:

```
c = (int) Math.ceil(100.0 * a / b);
```

Comment: `c = (int) Math.round(100.0 * a / b);` will give 47 which is intended

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm getting 18/38=45 and 13/38=35 for some reason though?

Comment: @BigMon the text of your question and the example you gave contradict each other. E.g., 13/38 is roughly 34.21% - if you want to round it up like the text says you'll get 35, which the code returns; If you want to get 34 that would be rounding down, and you should use `floor` instead of `ceil` - or, of course, you could just use `round` to get the nearest integer.

Comment: @Mureinik that's my bad, I changed ceil to round as you said and it seems to work as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = (int) Math.round(100.0 * a / b);
```

This should give desired result.

Comment: `Math.floor` always rounds down better to use `Math.round`.

Comment: Correct, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int a=18,b=38,c=0;
c = (int) Math.round(100.0 * a / b);    
System.out.println(c);
}
```

As @Mureinik said that `a` and `b` are integers,they will use integer division.
you should multiply 100 by a like above. and keep using `.round` instead of `.ceil` inorder to get 47 as output which is intended `.ceil` will give you 48 as output.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do follow things to get the result

```
Double res= Double.valueof(a/b);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String num= decimalFormat.format(res);
Int finalResult = Integer.valueof(num)*100;
```

Thanks

Comment: Adding a formatter for the purpose of a division is unnecessary and just wrong. You format and create a string just to make an int out of it.